# Получение текстовых данных из строк таблицы

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, dataframe, yandex-appmetrica

Выгружаю из Appmetrica данные по поисковой выдаче.
Использую для этого библиотеки requests, json, urllib
Коротко сам запрос:

```
url = '{host}/logs/v1/export/events.json?'.format(host=API_HOST)+ url_params
r = requests.get(url, headers=header_dict)
```

Более подробно можно прочитать в [справке appmetrica](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/docs/mobile-api/logs/ref/events.html)

На выходе получаю данные наподобие этих:

```
{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"па"}
{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пан"}
{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананг"}
{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананги"}
{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"панангин"}
```

Прошу подсказать, каким образом я могу оставить только для дальнейшей обработки:

```
па
пан
пананг
пананги
панангин
```

Это пример с конкретным товаром. Регионы могут быть другие, количество символов до названия товаров также меняется.

пример самого датафрейма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'event_json':['{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"па"}',
'{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пан"}',
'{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананг"}',
'{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананги"}',
'{"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"панангин"}']})

res = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x["event_json"])), axis=1)

print(res["Поисковой запрос"])
```

```
0          па
1         пан
2      пананг
3     пананги
4    панангин
Name: Поисковой запрос, dtype: object​
```

соответственно,

```
res["Поисковой запрос"].to_list()
```

даст вам простой список вместо серии:

```
['па', 'пан', 'пананг', 'пананги', 'панангин']
```

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо! Помогли так помогли!

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[
             {"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"па"},
             {"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пан"},
             {"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананг"},
             {"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"пананги"},
             {"Регион":"Башкортостан Респ","Город":"Агидель г","Аптека":"Аптека не выбрана","Поисковой запрос":"панангин"}
      ]

for el in data:
    print (el['Поисковой запрос'])
```

Вывод:

```
па
пан
пананг
пананги
панангин
```

Пример самого датафрейма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня весь массив данных находится в датафрейме. При выполнении кода получаю ошибку              
   1 for el in df1:
----> 2     print (el['Поисковой запрос'])

TypeError: string indices must be integer.    Подскажи. пожалуйста, что поправить? Пример (скан) датафрейма приложен.

Comment: если немного видоизменить код, то также появляется ошибка:                                                                  
for el in df1['event_json']:
    print (el['Поисковой запрос'])

Comment: Нужно точно определиться, что у Вас json, серии или датафрейм.

Comment: Соглашусь, я не полностью описал условие задачи. У меня датафрейм, полученный из json данных. Условие, как оно представлено в задании, действительно могло ввести в заблуждение. Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Он помог мне в любом случае сдвинуться дальше